# Import users attributes from CSV file to Active Directory ( Updating AD )

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory, quest

I am trying to import some of the parameters from csv file to AD.I want to match the data by e-mail.I am using Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell.

```
Import-Csv c:\Test.csv |ForEach-Object {
Set-QADUser 'ou=User,ou=Accounts,ou=PL,dc=test,dc=com'  
if(($_.E-mail Address)=mail){ $_.HR Department Code -department 
$_.HR Department Code -telephoneNumber $_.Reports to L1 Formal Name -manager}
else
(Write-Host 'ERROR, User not present in AD')
}
```

What is wrong with this loop? Is it possible to do it with this white spaces like in "HR Department Code" , I tried replacing it with variables but it does not work. I was using this idea to write this. I am using $_. to match it with my column/att name from csv

http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/update-active-directory-user-accounts-from-csv-file/

**Update

Code that I am currently using:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Test_Peoplesoft.csv' | foreach-object{set-qaduser -mail $_.'E-mail Address' -Department $_.'HR Department Code'  -telephoneNumber $_.'HR Department Code'}
```

Right now nothing is happening, it just starts and never stops, looks like nothing happens.
I have skipped manager field since there has to be a login and in my csv file is right now in this field full name of a supervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that your if statement is actually comparing your csv email and your AD email. Just use the email as the identity parameter:

```
  Import-Csv $file | foreach-object{set-qaduser $_.email -Department $_.department -Manager $_.manager -Title $_.title -ObjectAttributes @{employeeID=($_.employeeID)}}
```

Obviously there are some attributes I added for the example that you aren't using. Also replace my header names with your actual header names. I also try to avoid spaces in my headers in CSVs. the none standard attributes like employee ID and extension attributes etc will need to be set in the -objectAttributes

Comment: I do not really get the part "$_.email -Department" , why do You match email field from csv to department in AD ? I need to match by email and then update department field and  telephoneNumber with same data and update manager field.

Comment: I just don't get how you compare them.

Comment: $_.email is not associated with -department.  How powershell works is parameter is always on the left and value on the right. In set-qaduser or set-aduser the first parameter is always -identity <something> in my case $_.email And since its powershell and the identity value is required it assumes your first value is an identity value so you dont need to include -identity.  The next part is -department and to the right of that was the department value from CSV $_.department. and it goes on from there. hope that explains it better for you. let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I am constantly getting errors on this command like Missing an argument for parameter 'Email'.Specify a parameter of type 'System.String'   This is my command :                                     Import-Csv c:\Test_People.csv |ForEach-Object {
Set-QADUser 'ou=User,ou=Accounts,ou=PL,dc=test,dc=com' $_.e-mail -mail $_.'HR Department Code' -department $_.'HR Department Code' -telephoneNumber $_.'Reports to L1 Formal Name' -manager}                   I am using names of the columns from csv.

Comment: So I am assuming all your users already exist and you just want to match a csv record with AD record by email. If this is the case you dont need to supply a OU path and your parameter names need to be on the left.  Also since you are using email as the identity parameter you need that as the first value: Import-Csv c:\Test_People.csv |ForEach-Object {Set-QADUser -Identity $_.'e-mail' -department $_.'HR Department Code'  -manager $_.'Reports to L1 Formal Name'}  I suggest you read up on positional parameters somewhere like here: http://blog.mischel.com/2012/02/03/powershell-parameter-parsing/

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot validate argument on parameter'Identity'.The argument is null or empty. I checked it with my csv file and there are no spelling errors.I am using Windows XP.

Comment: what version of powershell are you running?  Also windows XP is no longer a secure OS.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change operating system.I think I am running version2.                                                                                                                                 PS C:\WINNT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1      

______________________________________________________________________________________________________
PS C:\WINNT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Get-Host

Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 2.0

Comment: Can it be somehow connected with culture settings ? I have CurrentCulture   : pl-PL
CurrentUICulture : en-US

Comment: can you edit your main thread and at the bottom put update: and your latest code you are using?

Comment: Import-Csv 'C:\Test_Peoplesoft.csv' | foreach-object{set-qaduser -identity $_.'E-mail Address' -Department $_.'HR Department Code'  -telephoneNumber $_.'HR Department Code'}  user that I replaced -mail with -identity.  Email is your identity param

Comment: Tried this one , it says that it cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'.The argument is null or empty.